# jQuery upload, boostraper keeps overiding my css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I wanted to use PHP jQuery upload with the colored buttons, file gallery and all the cool stuff. However this means I have to use the bootstrapper for css with overrides my page settings (divs change settings for margins and such).

Is there a way to have the bootstrapper css just for the jQuery upload elements?

I tried putting the bootstrapper css links above my stuff and even added !important to all my css settings, but I cant get it working properly.

Comment: Just strip out the styles you want for the buttons and toss out the rest. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: @Jack that isn't a good solution... you have to customize bootstrap every time you get an other (newer) version... that is a problem with all frameworks....

Comment: @marcel There's nothing to update if just wants the buttons styles how they currently are. I took his question that he likes the upload styles, but doesn't want to use the whole library. There's no difference between just pulling those styles out of the framework or writing your own.

Comment: Bootstrap exists for good reason. Is there any reason you cannot style your site *within the constraints of bootstrap*, rather than constantly be fighting against it? We moved over to Bootstrap-first styling for all new projects and find it much easier that way.

Comment: The reason why Im fighting with it is because Im just trying to plug jQuery upload to my site with is already created with all the css styles and stuff. I kinda dont want to redo all that stuff to fit everything together again.
@Jack, oh so I can customize what bootsrapper will be spat out? well in this case cool. Ill check it out for sure. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, or you can grab the un-minified css source and just copy out the styles you want.

Answer (score 1):

Place your site css file after all other CSS files, if your site shares any id's or classes with Bootstrap and is placed before Bootstrap then Bootstrap is last seen and re-declares those id's and classes which is why it's overriding your site's CSS so place the link below bootstrap.css :-)

Comment: I followed Jack's advice and complied my own version that dosent mess up my site layout. Everything seems to be working correctly. Now I need to find a way to prevent uploading files other then images. There are answers here, but I hardly understand word written here. Im new to this stuff.

Comment: use php to save file extensions as variables and do a switch/if statement that says if $file_extension != '.jpg' { //your code } else { echo 'Can't upload anything other than images'; } and if that doesn't make sense the PHP manual is really helpful, especially the user notes which helped me tones!